# How to help deserializer understand that generics don't need Deserialize bound

Tags: rust, serde

Consider the following code:

```
use std::{marker::PhantomData};
use serde::{Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Parent<A: Default, B> {
    value_parent: Child<A, B>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Child<A, B> {
    value_child: usize,

    phantom_b: PhantomData<B>,

    #[serde(skip)]
    no_need_to_deser: A
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct NonDeserializeable1;
#[derive(Default)]
struct NonDeserializeable2;


fn main() {
    // This works :
    let deser_child: Result<Child<NonDeserializeable1, NonDeserializeable2>, _> = serde_json::from_slice(b"123");

    // This doesn't : 
    //  - the trait bound `NonDeserializeable1: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    //  - the trait bound `NonDeserializeable2: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    let deser_parent: Result<Parent<NonDeserializeable1, NonDeserializeable2>, _> = serde_json::from_slice(b"123");
}
```

So,

- Serde understands that a structure does not need generics to have Deserialize bound if they are used in a PhantomData field, or an explicitly skipped field of this structure
- Serde doesn't understand the absence of need to have Deserialize bound if the generics are used in sub-structure that itself doesn't need them to have Deserialize bound

I feel like there must be a way to at least manually indicate it?

Comment: There is [`#[serde(bounds…)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#bound).

Comment: @Caesar Yes, I've looked at that feature but that seems to be an alternative to indicate HOW the trait should be deserialized - resulting in building structure anyways. I'd like to avoid having to do that at all, considering it's unnecessary

Comment: @Raywell no, it's precisely a way to indicate what bounds should be applied on the derived `Serialize` and `Deserialize` implementations. It doesn't change any behaviour ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9875d328051f90bfda6139739f92c442)).

Comment: @Jmb Oh I haven't realized empty bound is possible, and is in fact the way I've looked for ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of macros (and the rustc as a whole), `serde`'s `derive(Deserialize)` macro can only look at the struct or enum it's currently being run on. So when deriving (=auto-generating) a `Deserialize` implementation for `Parent`, serde knows nothing about how `Child` looks and can't deduct that it doesn't need bounds.

Just tell it explicitly to use no bounds for any of the type parameters

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "")]
pub struct Parent<A: Default, B> {
    value_parent: Child<A, B>,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dea4f0ca2f2916c6853a7957c094d536)

Though

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "A: Default")]
pub struct Parent<A, B> {
    value_parent: Child<A, B>,
}
```

is probably cleaner.

You've added a comment about a structure that you consider unnecessary to be built, but I'm not sure I understand which structure that is.

- You will need deserializers for `Parent` and `Child`, as both of them are actually constructed when you invoke `from_slice`. If you use <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Expand Macros</kbd> on the playground link, you'll see that no other code is generated.
- Both `PhantomData<B>` and `A` do need actual instances to be constructed at runtime, since you could access them with `deser_child.no_need_to_deser`, for example.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks ! As to answer your points - this is a simplified version of the problem, I have a big structure constructed with intial deserialization (which generics aren't involved in), and other data such as `Vec<A>` - intialized to `Vec::new()` (hence the `A:Default` bound) through use of `serde(deserialize_with=my_method)`, which is manipulated at runtime after the object is done deserializing.